# multi Key shadowing

Tags: tokens, erc-20, optimization

is there anyway i can implement Multi Key Shadow in ERC20 token Smart Contract ? is there any code/ function  to implement in smart contract or so ? Google can only tell me how it can implemented in Blockchain there is not any specific way or definition how it can be implemented in Ethereum Blockchain ?

Comment: What is multi key shadow?

Comment: https://patents.google.com/patent/US9634836  read this , will help you to understand what is key shadowing